# extending a javascript function with parameters

Tags: javascript

I think extending the function is working correctly but I am not sure how to handle the parameters that are passed into the function, right now I get a x is undefined error.

**Original function:**

```
_adloadCallback = function(x, y) {
  //
}
```

**Extended function:**

```
(function() {
 _adLoadCallbackExtend =_adloadCallback();
 _adloadCallback = function() {
    console.log("Before");
   _adLoadCallbackExtend.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log("After");
  }
})();
```

Comment: Remove the `()` in `_adLoadCallbackExtend =_adloadCallback();`.  You want to set the variable to the function, not call it.  Also, you should probably add `var` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line two, you are seting `_adLoadCallbackExtend` to being the result of calling `_adloadCallback` instead of setting it to `_adloadcallback` itself, which is what I think you are trying to do. Just get rid of the `()` at the end of the second line.

Answer (score 1):

```
_adLoadCallbackExtend =_adloadCallback();
```

should be

```
_adLoadCallbackExtend =_adloadCallback;
```

your way has `_adLoadCallbackExtend` be the result of calling `_adloadCallback` with no arguments instead of a "pointer" to the function